# 20.04 won't boot on Lenovo T470 while in docking station

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

Earlier today I tried to do the upgrade option from my 19.10. In mid-package install it froze, locking the screen and computer (Lenovo T470). I had to turn it off, but turning it back on only gave me an "Uh-oh" message. I then downloaded the 20.04 Desktop iso and made an install USB. I tried reinstalling, but it complained bitterly and unresolvably about "No EFI system partition was found". I then had no option other than to install beside the partially installed 20.04. That accomplished after two tries, I was able to get my personal files saved off. I then did a clean/total new install on the machine. This seemed to go fine, delivering me after a restart to my new 20.04 install. But a subsequent reboot hangs at the revolving circle/Lenovo display. How can I proceed?

**Update**

A subsequent reinstall, install on other Lenovo products, as well as experimentation, has revealed that U20.04 does not boot while docked in its T470 appropriate docking station (ThinkPad Pro Dock 40A1), i.e., as long as the T470 is not docked, it boots just fine. Once booted, I redock and it remains good. BTW, while docked log-out/log-in does not work, either, but does when undocked.

Comment: I have the similar situation. Just found even more info - Thinkpad boots while it's docked but with disconnected additional monitors. So probably the problem is in video drivers. I've tried to add option 'nomodeset' to Grub config and laptop boots but video is terrible. So need to continue research and fix Ubuntu 20.04 booting problem on Lenovo Thinkpad.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm running a 4K monitor (HDMI), as well as a 1080 (VGA) on the dock in addition to the laptop screen. Occasionally, I had problems with 19.10 (not getting the signal), but never a boot problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. My L450 does not boot while docked (ThinkPad Pro Dock 40A1), but it boots with disconnected additional monitor. All has worked while i disabled boot splash screen (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash" in /etc/default/grub).

Comment: I can confirm that replacing line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash"` in `/etc/default/grub` fixed the issue. Also after editing need to execute `update-grub`. Thanks.It works