# Lenovo laptop sleeps after booting in docking station in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, suspend, lenovo, docking

In a possibly related issue, I've got two Lenovo laptops that will boot in their respective docking stations, but after a few seconds, goes to sleep after logging on.

You need to hit the docking station power button to wake them up.   This may be related to:

[20.04 won't boot on Lenovo T470 while in docking station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230122/20-04-wont-boot-on-lenovo-t470-while-in-docking-station)

Any thoughts on this?

I tried installing dconf-editor, and changing the behavior so nothing happens when the laptop is closed and on AC power, but the behavior didn't change.